# Run only one package test cases scala

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I have the package structure as:

```
    src ->  test -> scala -> notification
```

Inside notification i have two packages unit and integration.

unit package has the unit tests and integration package has integration tests. I want to execute only the unit test cases. Is there i way i can do it by sbt test only?

for one class, i know it can be done like this:
I have tried for the one class but do not know how to do it for a pacakge.

```
sbt "test:testOnly *LoginServiceSpec"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`testOnly` allows you to [run wildcards](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#testOnly) using `*`. So if all your tests are in package namespace `x` you can call

```
> testOnly x.*
```

This wildcard can be put everythere, so if you have a subpackage in `x`, but all your tests end with e.g. `Spec` you could run

```
> testOnly x.*Spec
```

However if you are using integration test I recommend [creating a separate configuration](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests) for them so that you would run:

```
> test
```

for unit tests and

```
> it:test
```

for integration test. Then you would put them in `src/it/scala`. directory.

Comment: would it be src/it/scala or src/main/it/scala?

I have added the library dependency 

"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % 3.0.0 %  "it,test"

I have it like src/it/resources and src/it/scala

Comment: You can run `show it:sourceDirectories` or `show it:sourceDirectory` and you'll see which one is used by sbt.

Comment: I have added the library dependency 

"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % 3.0.0 %  "it,test"

I have it like src/it/resources and src/it/scala

I am getting No such setting/task

Comment: Then work with this instruction https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests - you have to set up it tests first.

Comment: I have done this:lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(
    Defaults.itSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     ...
    ) 
  )

Comment: I am getting lot of errors not found: value contentType
[error]         contentType should ===(ContentTypes.`application/json`)

Comment: Though i am able to run from intellij. But i need to get it working from linux terminal

Comment: sbt show it:sourceDirectory gives me not a valid key

Comment: I think it is a source directory issue for sure because when i compile my main project i do not get any compilation error only while running sbt it:test i  get errros.

Comment: Try running things in sbt shell instead of calling things from command line, it allows some introspection e.g. command completion. Or try using `"` - `sbt "show it:sourceDependencies"`, `sbt "show it:libraryDependencies"`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```sh
sbt "test:testOnly notification.unit.*"
```